# Polymorphism - correct understood? (JAVA)

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have been reading about polymorphism and would like to ask, if this is a correct example of polymorphism:

Interface:

```
public interface Language {
  public void talk();
}
```

Two different classes that inherit it:

```
public class Jimmy implements Language{
  public void talk(){
    System.out.println("Jimmy talks English");
  }
}

public class David implements Language{
  public void talk(){
    System.out.println("David talks Spanish");
  }
}
```

Class to run:

```
public class RunProgram(){
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Jimmy j = new Jimmy();
    David d = new David();
    j.talk();
    d.talk();
  }
}
```

The output should be:

Jimmy speaks English
David speaks Spanish

The idea of this is that the talk method is inherited from the interface and that the two classes (rather objects) determine what the output exactly is, so the output depends on which object you create and run the method from. Sorry if I am asking something that might be easy, and this example may not even be that good but I hope that it can illustrate my idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, except for usually reference is of `Language` (i.e. interface type) , and OOPically it would make more sense of interface name is `Person` or `Human` or something

Comment: Thanks alot! I knew that my example was not of the best, but certainly you know how to improve it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Jimmy j = new Jimmy();
David d = new David();
j.talk();
d.talk();
```

No, there's no polymorphism involved in the above code. Delete the interface `Language` and the code won't even notice.

The way to demonstrate polymorphism in action must involve the interface as the static type of the variables:

```
Language j = new Jimmy(), d = new David();
j.talk();
d.talk();
```

However, an example which truly showcases polymorphism as a useful language feature arises when you involve a method written against the interface type:

```
public void printTheTalk(String name, Language lang) {
   System.out.println(name + " says " + lang.talk());
}
```

Now you can see how that method has no idea of even the existence of the concrete type of the objects, yet it can work with them.

Comment: Okay, so you have to create the object of the interface class before it would turn to a polymorphism, because as you say, if I delete the interface, it does not affect the code at all, as I haven't used "Language" when creating the objects. So are these two objects of Language or of Jimmy and David?

And is this also abstraction as we use an interface or how's it?

I appreciate your help

Comment: You must learn to distinguish the *static* type of variables (and more generally, expressions) and the *dynamic* type of the objects they refer to. Objects always have a concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

This is close.  The point of polymorphism is that you can have a reference to an interface or superclass, which doesn't care which concrete class (`Jimmy` or `David`) the object really is.

If you were to use

```
Language j = new Jimmy();
Language d = new David();
```

then this demonstrates polymorphism.  The variables `j` and `d` only care that they are `Language`s, but the specific implementation of `talk()` is called later.

Comment: Thanks alot for help! You may also answer the quesion(s) asked to "Marko" under his answer. I didn't want to duplicate it here also (would look like spam).

Comment: The objects are really of type `Jimmy` and `David` at runtime, but the compiler sees the variables of type `Language` and doesn't care what their actual runtime types are/will be.  It just cares that it they are of type `Language`, so it can be guaranteed that a `talk()` method exists and can be called on the objects that these reference variables refer to.